# How long it takes for GRE score to be delivered to graduate school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre, deadlines

I would like to know how long it takes for a General computer based GRE score to be delivered to graduate school in US. Some graduate schools mention do not take GRE later than specific date so I am wondering does it really take long time to send the score online?

Comment: As an aside, the reason that schools ask for your GRE by a specific date is usually linked to the fact that the score is part of your application, which will likely be considered incomplete and in a holding pattern until you get your scores in, so regardless of the "take by" date, you should probably take the exam as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [ETS website](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/scores/get/), for the online general GRE (emphasis mine):

> About **10–15 days after your test date**, your official scores will be available in your My GRE Account, and your **scores will be sent to the score recipients you designate**

It is up to the receiving institution to decide [how they want to receive those scores](https://www.ets.org/gre/institutions/scores/receive/): online (which doesn't add additional delivery time), or paper mail (which adds some additional shipping time).