# GRE score sending how long

Tags: gre

This question is similar to [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29864/how-long-it-takes-for-gre-score-to-be-delivered-to-graduate-school) but is different enough I felt I should ask it separately.

I am wondering how long it will take a given institution to receive my General GRE scores from ETS.  Note: I am not asking how long it will take after I take a test for the scores to be sent.  These are scores from a test I took almost two years ago; I am asking how long it will take for scores already available to be sent and available.

If it matters, I am putting my score submission request into ETS on Jan. 2.  I don't know if some times of the year are busier for them than others and thus processing and sending times may vary.

Comment: You should contact ETS to ask about that https://www.ets.org/gre/contact#general_inquiries

Generally I'd say that processing and sending times should be somewhat the same. But I think that mail delivery would depend on how far the institute is from ETS.

Comment: @MohamedKhamis Can you please turn this into an answer so that I can vote it up?

Answer (score 1):

You should contact ETS to ask about that https://www.ets.org/gre/contact#general_inquiries

Generally I'd say that processing and sending times should be somewhat the same. But I think that mail delivery would depend on how far the institute is from ETS.